# Merge of n matrices without loop

Tags: matlab, join, matrix, merge, inner-join

I want to do something like an inner join with n Matrices, which have 2 columns (first column is the key, second one the value). I want to extract the values with keys, which are part of all matrices. The simplest idea that came to my mind was a n-1 loop that joins always two matrices with the inner join Function, after converting them to tables. So at the end I have a Matrix with n+1 columns, after converting it back from table to matrix.

For example I have:

```
A =[1,5;2,8;4,9] , B = [1,9;2,7;3,11;4,20;6,78], C = [1,4;2,1;4,7;5,9]
```

The final matrix should then be:

```
[1,5,9,4;2,8,7,1;4,9,20,7]
```

Thank you very much

Comment: Isn't `innerjoin` a function that operates on tables, not matrices?

Comment: can you provide some code that demonstrates what you're trying to do?

Comment: Yes, thats true. I would convert the matrices to tables, do the joins and then convert it back to a matrix.

Comment: I'm not sure how to accomplish what you want, but I'm really wondering what the purpose of this procedure.is.  `innerjoin`, to my knowledge, is used to return a collection of values from two tables that have a matching key value (or something like that).  How is this to be applied to a numeric matrix?

Comment: I've got multiple matrices with two columns, in the first one there is the Key, and the second one the value. I want to extract the values with keys, which are part of all matrices. I don't have any code so far.

Comment: @Kugelschreiber_Y: That comment roughly explains what you are trying to achieve, your original question does not. Please edit the question including that information and a small example.